# Notepad++ Tab font is too large and cannot be changed

Tags: notepad++

I opened Notepad++ today and the font size is inexplicably large. I first tried changing the Global and Default Font Size under Settings > Style Configurator which will change the editor font but does not effect the tab font size. I looked into the issue further but I can't find a working solution.

I did change the theme to Obsidian and changed the Font to Consolas about 2 months ago but I have not made any changes since that time and haven't seen this issue until today.

[image]

I have seen this question asked before and however there does not seem to be a verified solution or any follow up if the solutions provided even worked.

I tried changing The "Reduced" option under Settings > Preferences however checking it makes the font larger which as I understand it should actually have me it smaller. Even when it's the smallest it's still too large.

Reduced ON: 
[image]

Reduced OFF:
[image]

I also tried going to Settings > Style Configurator and changing the Active Tab Focused, Active Tab Unfocused and Active Tab Text however they are all greyed out and cannot be edited.

[image]

Comment: I had similar problems in the past. There is a place where you can configure the font, but if my memory serves me right, you really do need to close Notepad++ and reopen it to fix it. It may also be a windows setting.

Comment: do you have screen scaling (windows) or a high-dpi monitor enabled? Have you tried toggling the high-dpi aware option in the compatibility tab of the executable's properties (windows setting, right click the shortcut or exe)

Comment: Yorik you sent me on the right path. I changed to a 4k monitor 2 weeks ago and rebooted yesterday which would explain why the issue just popped up. I changed the setting you suggested (nothing happened) then rebooted and checked the "Reduced" box and BOOM it worked. I can answer my own question but you really deserve the credit so if you post the above as an answer I would accept it or whatever the proper etiquette in this situation.